# oop classes in an Angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop

Anyway I *think* these are oop classes, I'm new to this.  I'm trying to move some complex stuff written by someone else into an Angular service and I can't seem to get the syntax right.  I have something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .service('myService', function () {

    var service = this;

    this.Util = {

     extend: function (blah) {
       //blah blahh
       return blah

    },

     create: Object.create || (function (blah) {

       //blah blah
        return blah

    })(),

     //more blah blah

   };


    var something = this.Util.create(blah);

});
```

I hope that's enough detail to tell what I'm doing wrong.  It's telling me it 'Cannot read property 'create' of undefined'.

Comment: There's a lot more to it than that, this is just an example of the syntax I'm using, I was hoping there was something obviously wrong with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i will try to give a you a way to do it :

**service**

```
angular.module('myApp').service('Util', [function () {

     this.extend = function (blah) {
       //blah blahh
       return blah

    };

     this.create: function (blah) {

       //blah blah
        return blah

     },
     // should write new methods like this.myMethod
}]);
```

**controller**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl',[
    'Util',
    function(UtilSvc) {
        var something = UtilSvc.create(); // call your service method
    }
]);
```